# Why tabView jump one view back in orientation change?

Tags: swiftui

I am using down simple code for tabView. when I change the orientation of simulator, the app tab jump one tab back. like this if you are in page 2 goes to 1, but it must stays at page 2 how ever I changed the orientation. or if you are in page 3 jump to page 2. why this unwanted jump happens?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var currentPage: Int = 1


    var body: some View {
        
        
        ZStack
        {

            Color.gray.ignoresSafeArea()
            
            
            TabView(selection: $currentPage)
            {
                Text("Hi 1").tag(0)
                Text("Hi 2").tag(1)
                Text("Hi 3").tag(2)
                
            }
            .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .never))
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
            
        }
  
        
    }
}
```

Comment: The weird thing about this issue is when you turn the device back to portrait (from the landscape), it doesn't jump.

Comment: Really bug of PageTabViewStyle, worth submitting feedback to Apple.

Comment: I mean I should do it? I do not know the steps or how?

Comment: @Omid See this page: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

Comment: thanks to @pawello2222 and Asperi, I send the issue to Apple let's see what happens next.

Comment: Any feedback from Apple? Still an issue with xcode 13.1 and their beta 13.2 (as of this comment)

Comment: Has anyone managed to fix this issue?

Comment: Please, try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/72963653/2003968

Comment: yes, but it is not solving the issue, the bug still there.